# Join table on multiple OR conditions

Tags: c#, sql

I have a 2 table one call A another one Call B
A has the same fields as B

I want to do something like

```
everything In A
and
distinct everything In
A join B on 
A.CustomerAccount = B.CustomerAccount
Or A.Email = B.Email
Or (A.CustomerAccount = B.CustomerAccount and A.Email = B.Email)
```

just a brief, is there any other way to do it?
(is there a more efficient way to do it?)

Comment: Please add some sample data for the two tables.  `everything in A` would seem to imply doing a left outer join from `A` to `B`, but this is not certain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the best solution in this case would be to try and use the [UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) operator and looking at [UNION examples](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/union).

the basic parctice - instead of `OR` your query will look like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT tpl.*, a.MidParentAId as 'MidParentId', 1 as 'IsMidParentA' 
    FROM TopLevelParent tpl 
    INNER JOIN MidParentA  a ON a.TopLevelParentId = tpl.TopLevelParentID
UNION
    SELECT tpl.*, b.MidParentBId as 'MidParentId', 0 as 'IsMidParentA'  
    FROM TopLevelParent tpl 
    INNER JOIN MidParentB b ON b.TopLevelParentId = tpl.TopLevelParentID
UNION
    SELECT tpl.*, 0 as 'MidParentId', 0 as 'IsMidParentA'  
    FROM TopLevelParent tpl 
    WHERE tpl.TopLevelParentID NOT IN (
       SELECT pa.TopLevelParentID 
       FROM TopLevelParent tpl
       INNER JOIN MidParentA  a ON a.TopLevelParentId = tpl.TopLevelParentID
    UNION
       SELECT pa.TopLevelParentID 
       FROM TopLevelParent tpl
       INNER JOIN MidParentB b ON h.TopLevelParentId = tpl.TopLevelParentID
    )
) tpl
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select a.*
from a
union all
select distinct b.*
from b
where exists (select 1
              from a
              where b.CustomerAccount = a.CustomerAccount or
                    b.Email = a.Email
             );
```

I removed the condition:

```
(b.CustomerAccount = a.CustomerAccount and b.Email = a.Email)
```

because it is redundant.